# Swing окно типа Подождите

Tags: java, swing

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли в библиотеке Swing специальное окно состояния процесса типа Подождите идёт загрузка, которое само бы закрывалось по окончании процесса?

Comment: готового нет, но сделать можно

Comment: С помощью JDialog?

Comment: Да. делаете его модальным, скрываете кнопки управления и закрываете его программно когда вам нужно.